# Multiplos objetos com canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Galera, não encontrei post igual.. então mandem o link se acharem um.

To com um enorme problema, estou criando um game daqueles que a bolinha tem que quebrar quadrados na tela e ja tenho tudo pronto, menos os quadrados a serem quebrados.

Meu problema é que crio um objeto bloco com os dados do bloco. E quando eu faço:

```
var bloco = new bloco(posiçãox,posiçãoy)
```

eu crio um bloco na tela, mas quando faço outro bloco, não consigo. Ou quando o `var` tem um nome diferente de bloco.

Tentei:

```
var bloco2 = new bloco.constructor();
```

mas n sei onde inserir os parametros do objeto `(posx e posy)`;

Alguem sabe como me ajudar? Tenho que fazer uns 270 e não dá pra fazer manualmente pq eles aparecem de forma aleatória na tela.

Os objetos estão no contexto de um canvas 2d.

Comment: Olá Ramon, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow. Você poderia fazer um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) com o exemplo citado para podermos ficar mais por dentro do contexto?

Comment: Aqui esta o link https://jsfiddle.net/n58pkm02/

Comment: Não precisava ser o jogo todo meu amigo, apenas o trecho em que está com problemas.

Comment: pra não ter dúvidas coloquei o código todo, porque tem uma sequencia de "loops" para mostrar e interagir com os elementos, pensei que o erro pudesse n ser só no objeto, mas em outros elementos também.
mas o erro esta no objeto "bloco".. quero lançar varios iguais a ele.. as cores serão aleatórias, a pontuação e outros elementos farei depois que conseguir gerar as "copias" do bloco

Comment: depois que estiver pronto me avisa que quero jogar!!! rsrsrs

Comment: Valeu Galera.. Já consegui fazer todos os blocos aparecerem, inserindo eles num array. Agora cada um tem seus próprios metodos e tudo mais. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

vou mostrar como colorir a primeira "linha" de blocos e com base nesse faz quantas linhas o jogo for ter realmente, depois você da uma olhada na lógica e constrói eles direitinho com função, classe sei lá a metodologia que for usar neles.

```html
<style>
    *{ margin:auto;}
hr{width:100%; opacity:0.3;}
#topo{
 margin-bottom:1px;
    width:810px;
    height:80px;}
#scoretable{
    background-color:#23B361;
    float:left;
    width:610px;
    height:inherit;}
#marca{ 
    width:160px;
    height:inherit;
    float:left;}
#score{ 
    width:440px;
    height:inherit;
    float:right;}
#menubt{
    background-color:#23B361;
    float:right;
    width:198px;
    height:inherit;
    border:#FFF solid 1px;}
#menubt p{
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-size:38px;}
#bg{
    background-color:#2F2F2F;
    width:810px;
    height:500px;}
#gamearea{
    width:810px;
    height:450px;}
#blocarea{
    margin-bottom:-250px;
    width:inherit;
    height:250px;}
</style>
<body>
<nav id="topo">
    <div id="scoretable">
        <div id="marca">
        <!--<img src="http://i.imgur.com/oeof5Of.png" widht='160' height='80'>-->
        </div>
        <div id="score"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menubt">
    <p>MENU</p>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="bg">
    <div id="gamearea">
        <div id='blocarea'></div>
        <canvas id='canvas' width=810 height=500></canvas>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
    <script>
          //Inicio do código do canvas da tela
  var cnv = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')
  //Liga o game completo;
  cnv.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   // representar o tamanho máximo da tela onde movimenta os quadrados
   var w = 810;
   var h = 500;
   // Aqui cria as arrays que irão armazenar a posição dos quadrados (importante)
   var x = 390;
   var y = 300;
   // Aqui representará a velocidade dos nossos quadrados
   var vel = 15;
   
   var id;
   
   //Registro de game pause ou load game;
   var gameload = false;
   
   
  //Menus
  
  
  
  //Funções do game loop   
  //Da partida ao motor em 24frames por segundo
  function loading(){ 
   id = window.setInterval(motor, 1000/60);
   gameload = true;
  };
  function bloco(x, y){                        
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.w = 30;
   this.h = 20;
   this.color;
   this.colorcont = 0;
   var indice = 0;
  };
  bloco.prototype.colors = function(){
   var colors = Math.floor(Math.random()*70+1);
   if((colors > 0) && (colors < 10) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#6B6B6B';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors < 10) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#FFFFFF';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors > 10 && colors < 20) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#415FAC';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors > 20 && colors < 30) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#91CE9E';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors > 30 && colors < 40) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#E4E881';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors > 40 && colors < 50) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#EACC80';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors > 50 && colors < 60) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#EAA480';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
   if((colors > 60 && colors < 70) && this.colorcont == 0){ 
    this.color = '#CD87BA';
    this.colorcont = 1;
   }
  };
  bloco.prototype.render = function(){
                        cnv.beginPath(); 
   cnv.fillStyle = this.color;
   cnv.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  };
                
               /* criarBlocos=function(){
                    var tam = 0;
                    for( var i=0; i <= 27; i++){ // canvas com width 810, bloco tem 30 então são 27 por linha
                        var bloco = new bloco(tam,0);                                          
                        bloco.render();
   bloco.colors();
                        tam += 30;
                    }
                };*/
  
                var tam = 0;
                for( var i=0; i <= 27; i++){ // canvas com width 810, bloco tem 30 então são 27 por linha
                    var b = new bloco(tam,0);                                          
                    b.colors();            
                    b.render();                    
                    tam += 30+1;
                }
  //var bloco = new bloco(0,0);
  //var bloco2 = new bloco.constructor();
  
  //Dados da barra que segura a bola
  function barra(x, w, h){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 426;
   this.w = w;
   this.h = h;
   this.color = "#0D8961";
  };
  //Renderiza a barra
  barra.prototype.render = function(context){
   context.fillStyle = this.color;
   context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h); 
  };
  //Adiciona o movimento a variavel x de barra
  barra.prototype.move = function(pos){
   if(pos < canvas.width - this.w){
    this.x = pos;
   }
   if(pos > 0){
    this.x = pos;
   }
  };
  //Cria o objeto barra no sistema
  var barra = new barra(350,100,20);
  //Dados da bola seguindo os padrões
  function bola(x, y, raio, vel){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.raio = raio;
   this.vel = vel;
   this.color = "white";
   this.velx = this.vel;
   this.vely = this.vel;
   this.dirx = this.vel;
   this.diry = this.vel;
   
  };
  //Renderiza a bola
  bola.prototype.render = function(context){
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.raio,0,2*Math.PI);
   context.fillStyle = this.color;
      context.fill();
   context.closePath();
   
  };
  //Cria o movimento diagonal da bola
  bola.prototype.move = function(){
   //Lado Esquerdo da tela
   if(this.x < 10 && this.diry > 0) this.dirx = -this.dirx;
   if(this.x < 10 && this.diry < 0) this.dirx = -this.dirx;
   //Topo da tela
   if(this.y < 10 && this.dirx > 0) this.diry = -this.diry;
   if(this.y < 10 && this.dirx < 0) this.diry = -this.diry;
   //Lado direito da tela
   if(this.x > canvas.width - this.raio*2 && this.diry > 0) this.dirx = -this.dirx;
   if(this.x > canvas.width - this.raio*2 && this.diry < 0) this.dirx = -this.dirx;
   //Baixo da tela
   //Morte da bola
   if(this.y > 450 - this.raio*2 && this.dirx > 0){
    //função de registro de lifepoint
     lifePoint(); 
     this.x = 350;
     this.y = 400;
     this.diry = -this.diry;
   }
   //Morte da bola
   if(this.y > 450 - this.raio*2 && this.dirx < 0){
    //função de registro de lifepoint
     lifePoint();
     this.x = 350;
     this.y = 400;
     this.diry = -this.diry;
   }
   //Contato com a barra
   //Contato Topo
   if(bola.y + (bola.raio*2) > barra.y &&
      bola.y + (bola.raio*2) < barra.y + 5 &&
      bola.x < barra.x + barra.w &&
      bola.x + (bola.raio*2) > barra.x){
       if (this.dirx > 0){
      if (this.x > 0 && this.x < barra.x + 20){ 
       this.dirx = this.vel + this.vel/2;
       this.diry = this.vel - (this.vel*60/100); 
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 20 && this.x < barra.x + 40){
       this.dirx = this.vel;
       this.diry = this.vel  - (this.vel*40/100);      
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 40 && this.x < barra.x + 50){
       this.dirx = this.vel - this.vel/2;
       this.diry = this.vel;    
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 50 && this.x < barra.x + 60){
       this.dirx = this.vel - this.vel/2;
       this.diry = this.vel; 
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 60 && this.x < barra.x + 80){
       this.dirx = this.vel;
       this.diry = this.vel - (this.vel*40/100); 
      }
      if (this.x > barra.x + 80 && this.x < barra.x + barra.w){ 
       this.dirx = this.vel + this.vel/2;
       this.diry = this.vel - (this.vel*60/100); 
      }
       }
       if (this.dirx < 0){
        
         if (this.x > 0 && this.x < barra.x + 20){ 
       this.dirx = -(this.vel + this.vel/2);
       this.diry = (this.vel - (this.vel*60/100));
       
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 20 && this.x < barra.x + 40){
       this.dirx = -this.vel;
       this.diry = (this.vel  - (this.vel*40/100));
         
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 40 && this.x < barra.x + 50){
       this.dirx = -(this.vel - this.vel/2);
       this.diry = this.vel;
            
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 50 && this.x < barra.x + 60){
       this.dirx = -(this.vel - this.vel/2);
       this.diry = this.vel;
       
      }
      if(this.x > barra.x + 60 && this.x < barra.x + 80){
       this.dirx = -this.vel;
       this.diry = (this.vel - (this.vel*40/100));
       
      }
      if (this.x > barra.x + 80 && this.x < barra.x + barra.w){ 
       this.dirx = -(this.vel + this.vel/2);
       this.diry = (this.vel - (this.vel*60/100));
       
      }
       }
   }
   //Contato lateral
   if(bola.y + (bola.raio*2) > barra.y + 5 &&
      bola.x < barra.x + barra.w &&
      bola.x + (bola.raio*2) > barra.x){
     if (this.dirx > 0 || this.dirx < 0){ this.dirx = -this.dirx;}
     
   }
   
   this.x += this.dirx;
   this.y -= this.diry;
  };
  //Cria o objeto bola no sistema
  var bola = new bola(350, 400, 5, 5);
  //Renderiza todo o conteudo visual
  function render(){
   //cria os objetos
   barra.render(cnv);
   bola.render(cnv);
   
  };
  //Chama os movimentos
  function move(){
   barra.move();
   bola.move();
   
   
  };
  //Blocos
  function blocoMotor(){
                        //criarBlocos();
   
   //bloco.position();
  };
  //motor do game
   function motor(){
   //apaga a tela
   cnv.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   render();
   move();
   blocoMotor();
   
  };
  
  
  //Captura o movimento x do mouse
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        };
  };
  //Cria o movimento x da barra a partir do mouse
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  var PosX = 350;
  if(mousePos.x < 750){
    var PosX = mousePos.x - 50;
  }
  if(mousePos.x > 50){
    var PosX = mousePos.x - 50;
  }
  if(mousePos.x < 50){
    var PosX = 0;
  }
  if(mousePos.x > 750){
    var PosX = 710;
  }
  barra.move(PosX);
       }, false);
  
  //Controle de teclas para pause e load game
  document.onkeydown = startGame;
  function startGame(evt){
   //Tecla espaço keycode 32 inicia o game
   if(evt.keyCode == '32' && gameload == false){
    loading(); 
   }
   //Tecla p keycode 80 pausa o game
   if(evt.keyCode == '80'){
    pause();
   }
  };
  //Pause Game
  function pause(){
   window.clearInterval(id);
   gameload = false;
  }
  //Controle de life point
  function lifePoint(){
   alert('derrota');
   bola.dirx = bola.vel;
   bola.diry = -bola.vel;
  };
    </script>
```