# Texto dentro de cículo com canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estou iniciando em canvas e apesar de documentos muito bons pela web, surgem dúvidas específicas.

Por exemplo, eu gostaria de colocar um número dentro de um círculo, mas tenho conseguido apenas o número, e não o cículo.
Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("1",50,50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

Comment: vc nao teria que preencher o circulo primeiro e depois criar o texto?

Comment: Como eu disse, ainda estou começando. Imaginei que na terceira linha eu estivesse fazendo exatamente isso.

Comment: ctx.beginPath(); tenta isso
@edit
tem um post no stackoverflow ingles 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539837/how-to-draw-circles-in-html5-canvas-with-text-in-them
desenhe o circulo primeiro depois desenhe o texto em cima

Comment: Editei a pergunta conforme o indicado, mas continua sem funcionar... Abri o exemplo da resposta, e ao menos no meu navegador não funcionou.

Comment: Funcionou sim @LucasBertollo , eu havia colocado com fundo branco.
Coloque essa resposta para que eu aceite, vou voltar a pergunta para o que estava antes...

Comment: tem um código de um rapaz que ajudei a criar "blocos" da uma estudada p/ tu ver que maneiro é um joguinho http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82847/12032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segu em exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');


ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.arc(77,76,75,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle="grey";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();


ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.font="25px Verdana";
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fillText("1",50,50);



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Para aprender sobre as funções e parametros tem uma literatura boa e prática aqui:

> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp